# Dynamic Variables from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have currently hit a dead-end with my coding, I am rewriting a huge chunk of code that is related to both changing site wide options that are stored in a database, and also the same for applying permissions on individual users accounts.

On the settings page, I have various settings stored in a database that I want to retrieve from the database to form my page, with the results I have retrieved I then populate a select box for each individual setting with "enabled" or "disabled", as most of the settings are either 0 or 1.

My question is, what is the best way to fetch the data from the database and create dynamic variables to then use in my settings page? The structure of the table is: **id | setting_name | setting_value**. I only need setting_name and value, and I would like it if each variable that is made within the while loop was as follows;

setting_name = setting_value;

This is so then I can use that variable to populate my select box.

```
$sql_query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `setting`" );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql_query ) )
{           
$row['name'] = $row['value'];
}
```

I thought the code above would work, however the variable is never created.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: It's really important to not use `mysql_query` in new applications. You are likely to get yourself into serious trouble if you continue down this path.

Comment: @NullPointer Thanks for the heads-up, I have seen it time and time again on here and I would like to finally do something about it. What would you recommend for a project that is up to 70% complete? It uses mysql_* throughout so I am unsure as to what to do to change over. Thanks

Comment: if you used a same class for database than you dont need to do more work otherwise  make a class and use  .. and in checking/got time  just convert all

Comment: And would you suggest mysqli_* or PDO, I have been doing research and as far as I can see mysqli_* is near-enough the same as mysql_*, as I feel comfortable with mysql_* I thought it would be the best option for me, would you agree with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more $: `$$row['name'] = $row['value']`

Comment: It is that simple? Thank you very much I can not believe it is this simple, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @JakeBall are you easy with $$ ?

Comment: You'd be better off keeping them in an array.  With the approach above, you risk overwriting other variables on your page.

Comment: @NullPointer I can't really understand what you are saying with your comment, Sam I have purposely named my settings in the database to be non-conflictive, so I can rule that out!

Comment: @SamDufel also for the other answer

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this:

```
${$row[name]} = $row[value];
```

Also, you want to stop using `mysql_` functions as they are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). You should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for still can't believe it was so simple. I am currently looking at changing over to PDO but it seems to be a lot more complicated. However, thank you for your answer and I will look at implementing PDO in my future projects, and may even convert this project over to it!

Comment: @JakeBall It's more complex, but you only need to figure it out once. After that it's sooooo much better.